# Why use "break out" instead of "broken out"?

Tags: grammar, transitivity

> I had my purse stolen during my stay in London.

In this sentence, "stolen" is used insted of "steal".

> In my childhood, I had a fire break out.

In this sentence, "break out" is used instead of "broken out".
Why??

Comment: _I had a fire break out._ seems a little curious by itself.

Comment: ... 'We had a fire break out at the school' is idiomatic, though, KT.

Comment: Where are these sentences from?

Comment: On the subject of "curious;" to my ear "I/we had a fire break out..." is idiomatic for conversational English, but awkward or at least overly informal for written English, where I would suggest the sentence can be improved by removing useless/conversational words, leaving you with "a fire broke out..."

Comment: When I first read the title I thought the subject was pimples/zits/spots as in "My skin breaks out when I eat fast food"

Comment: Same reason why it's "cut" in "I had my hair cut" but "cut" in "I had someone cut my hair"!

Answer (score 4):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have) explains that ***have*** can mean:

> to suffer something that someone does to you:
>
> - She **had** her car stolen (= ***it was stolen***) last week.

Note that ***steal*** is a transitive verb used in the passive in your sentence. So, if ***your purse was stolen*** (by someone) it is natural and correct to say:

> I had my purse stolen.

***Break out*** is an intransitive verb, its action is performed by the fire itself, not by someone else. Therefore if ***a fire broke out*** (you can't use it in the passive voice with ***fire*** as a subject: **A fire was broken out by someone*), then it is correct to say

> In my childhood, I had a fire break out.

However, *I had a fire break out* is not very commonly used. Google gives only [154000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22had%20a%20fire%20break%20out%22&source=hp&ei=PTjTZMeUF_W28gK-h4OABg&iflsig=AD69kcEAAAAAZNNGTWnGubsMvPosKCKg5pMdUPBqdOI9&ved=0ahUKEwiHp5qn_86AAxV1m1wKHb7DAGAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5&oq=%22had%20a%20fire%20break%20out%22&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6IhYiaGFkIGEgZmlyZSBicmVhayBvdXQiMgUQIRigATIIECEYFhgeGB1IxRhQAFiGE3AAeACQAQCYAe0BoAHqBKoBBTAuMS4yuAEDyAEA-AEB-AEC&sclient=gws-wiz) hits of it. Also, it would be more idiomatic to specify ***where*** the fire broke out, as @Edwin explained in a comment. For example:

> In my childhood, I had a fire break out ***at my parent's house***.

Comment: On the right lines, but I think it's to do with whether the thing (fire, purse) is the agent or patient of the verb, rather than with transitive/intransitive *per se*: in "I had my best friend leave me"  and "I had a fire break out", the friend and the fire are the ones doing the leaving/breaking out, but "leave" is transitive and "break out" intransitive.

Comment: @StuartF I meant that an intransitive verb does not have passive, so "fire" can only be the subject, not the object of "break out".

Comment: 'Suffer' is perhaps over-prescriptive for non-causative 'have something V-ed': << I had my photograph taken by a famous photo-journalist last week; the first thing I knew about it was when Jill showed me her copy of the 'Daily Carrier Pigeon'. Then I received a cheque for £30. >>

Comment: @StuartF "I saw my cat eat (a mouse)" and "I saw my cat eaten (by an alligator)" has the active/passive distinction you are pointing towards.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Cambridge just gives more detailed subcategories of meaning. It has a different entry for the meaning you are referring to: _**to cause something to happen or someone to do something**: (We're having the house painted next month.)_

Comment: It's not all that rare to say "We had a fire break out".   *We had a fire break out in the hay loft.*

Comment: *We had a fire break out* emphasizes the *experiential* aspect.

Comment: No. I'm not straying into the causative usage. << I had my photograph taken by a famous photo-journalist last week; **the first thing I knew about it was** ...' ensures the purely eventive sense.  ' I had my photograph taken by a famous photo-journalist last week' here = 'A famous photo-journalist took my photograph last week'

Answer (score 2):

Why? Because they're different constructions, that's why. They both involve the auxiliary verb *have*, but that's just part of the construction, in each case.

> 1. *I had my purse stolen* is an **adversative** construction,
>    referring to some ill fortune befalling the subject of *had*.
>    Like *I had my tires slashed last night,* referring to vandalism of my car.

Note that (1) means "`Indef` stole my purse"; *purse* is the Object of *stole*, not its subject. The agent must be human, but does not occur in the construction.

> 2. *I had a fire break out* is also an adversative construction, but with the subject of *break out* present in an active intransitive clause. Like *I had a fire start in the carburetor* to describe an event. The causation is vague (fires don't start themselves) but the language is good for vague events.

So there are two kinds of adversative construction -- one with a passive participle (*have your bag stolen/lost/dropped/opened*) and not always something that's ill fortune -- and one with an infinitive (*had a fire break out*); both refer to the subject of *have* as the recipient of the fortune, though not necessarily its cause.

These are in contrast to the **causative** constructions with *have*, like

- *I had my tires rotated yesterday*, where *my tires* is the object of *rotate* and the subject of *have* is the person who causes the action in the clause containing the participle *rotated* -- it was my car and I told some indefinite person(s) to do the tires on it and they did it.
- *I had Billy rotate my tires yesterday* uses an infinitive instead of a passive participle; that's active and requires a subject *Billy*.

tl;dr: Don't worry about auxiliary verbs; look for **constructions**. They specify everything else.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I had my purse* [*stolen during my stay in London*].
>
> [2] *In my childhood, I had a fire* [*break out*].

These are both catenative constructions.

In [1] the catenative verb "had" has the bracketed past participial clause as its complement. "Had" is a perfect auxiliary requiring a past-participial complement clause, in this case the bracketed clause headed by the past participle "stolen".

In [2], by contrast, "had" is not a perfect auxiliary, so there's no perfect tense. The head of the bracketed complement clause is therefore not a past participle like it is in [1] but the plain form "break" with the preposition "out" as its complement.

Answer (score 1):

In those sentences, **stolen** refers to what happened to the purse and **break out** refers to what the fire did.

Compare:

> Yesterday, I had my tooth **begin** <sup>plain form of the verb</sup> to ache.

Yesterday, I  *felt* my tooth begin to ache.

> Yesterday, I had my tooth **pulled**  <sup>past participle</sup> by the dentist.

Yesterday, I *arranged* to have my tooth (be) **pulled** by a dentist.

(Yesterday, I *caused* my tooth to be pulled by a dentist.)

> Yesterday, I had my purse **stolen** <sup>past participle</sup>

You didn't *arrange* to have your purse stolen (although that is a possible, if highly improbable, parsing); rather you underwent the experience of having it (be) stolen.

> Yesterday, I had my arm **stung**  <sup>past participle</sup> (by a wasp).

Comment: I don't think the first example is Present Tense (that would be *Now my tooth **begins** to ache*). I think it's an unmarked infinitive - "unmarked" because ***begin*** isn't preceded by the "infinitive marker" ***to***.

Comment: Right you are on that. But it's sometimes called the "present infinitive". "tense" was my brain on autocomplete.

Comment: I'll leave me comment there, but I'm perfectly to upvote now you've changed "present tense" to "plain form of the verb". When I just googled for a "definition" of the latter, more than half the first page of results were specifically to do with *Japanese* (which language I don't know and never explicitly look into online, so it's not like google is influenced by my past searches there). Anyway, apparently the plain for in Japanese "tells you that the action is happening right now". But it sure looks like an infinitive in English to me!

Comment: It's "old school".